# How to Create table in flutter with dynamic content?

Tags: android, flutter, uitableview, flutter-layout, flutter-design

I want to create a table with the data inside the table to be fetch from internet(API)
As, we build `ListView.builder` is there any way to build `table` in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a table and insert data into it dynamically, you need a data model first. See the example below for more details.

**data.dart (data model):**

```
class NameOne{
    String sn, name, address, phone;
    
    NameOne({
        this.sn, 
        this.name, 
        this.address, 
        this.phone
    });
    //constructor

    factory NameOne.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json){
        return NameOne( 
          sn: json["sn"],
          name: json["name"],
          address: json["address"],
          phone: json["phone"]
        );
    } 
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testapp/data.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp()); 
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<NameOne> namelist = []; //list of names, you can generate it using JSON as well
    namelist.add(NameOne(sn:"1", name:"Name 1", address:"Address 1", phone: "Phone 1"));
    namelist.add(NameOne(sn:"2", name:"Name 2", address:"Address 2", phone: "Phone 2"));
    namelist.add(NameOne(sn:"3", name:"Name 3", address:"Address 3", phone: "Phone 3"));
    //add more adata here
  
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title:Text("Dynamic Data Table"), //title of app
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent, //background color of app bar
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child:Table( //if data is loaded then show table
            border: TableBorder.all(width:1, color:Colors.black45),
            children: namelist.map((nameone){ //display data dynamically from namelist List.
              return TableRow( //return table row in every loop
                      children: [
                        //table cells inside table row
                          TableCell(child: Padding( 
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child:Text(nameone.sn)
                            )
                          ),
                          TableCell(child: Padding( 
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child:Text(nameone.name)
                            )
                          ),
                          TableCell(child: Padding( 
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child:Text(nameone.address)
                            )
                          ),
                          TableCell(child: Padding( 
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child:Text(nameone.phone)
                            )
                          ),
                      ]
                );
            }).toList(),
          )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image: flutter table]

This is the way you can insert data to Flutter table dynamically,visit [How to Make Table and Insert data from PHP MySQL JSON Dynamically in Flutter App](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/30/how-to-make-table-and-insert-data-from-php-mysql-json-dynamically-flutter/) to see more details to create table from JSON data fetched with REST API.